# overlay submit feedback

Tags: 7, modal-dialogs

This might be a very simple question, but I can't figure out the answer.

I love the overlay module in drupal 7, but I am annoyed by the lack of visual feedback when a form is submitted in an overlay. eg. admin/structure/block, hitting submit doesn't give any indication that something is happening in the background.

I would love to know what I have to do to attach some behavior to the submit button of a form in an overlay that provides visual feedback that the form has been submitted (like greying out the overlay or something).

Comment: This is one of the reasons I turn off Overlay as soon as I can. :-)

Comment: Is this a question about how to add JavsScript or how to write JavaScript that does the above?

Comment: The question is what is the JavaScript that does the above. I know how to write and add it (different ways) but haven't been able to figure out WHAT to write

Answer (score 3):

I just added a block with following code to the content region of my administration theme

```
<style type="text/css">
#overlay-inactive {
 z-index:100;
 opacity:0.5;
 background-color:grey;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width:100%;
 height: 100%;
}
</style>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
   jQuery('#overlay').append('<div id="overlay-inactive">&nbsp;</div>');
  return true;
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, that would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jquery-loadmask](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/). It looks like it grays out the div and puts a throbber over it.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I don't think I even need another library. Guess I figured it out